# How do i insert a date in Sql Server 2008?

Tags: sql-server-2008

I'm trying to insert a date '05/01/2015' (mm/dd/yyyy) But it saved like

' 1901-02-08 00:00:00.000 '

How can i insert it in correct way .. ?

Comment: How are you inserting it? Directly in SSMS? Using some programming language? You need to show the code.

Comment: Can you also clarify if the issue is an incorrect date being saved or are you talking about the formatting you see when you select the data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Insert into Table1 (Date) values (convert(datetime,'05/01/2015',101))
```